# Stack using linked list. Struct field is of the same type as the struct

Tags: c++, struct, linked-list, stack

While practicing stack using linked list, I ran across the following piece of code:

```
class stack {
private:
    struct node {
        double value;
        node* next;
    };
    size_t stack_size;
    node* head;
...
}
```

As you can see, the struct `node` has a pointer field `*node`. How can a field be of the same type as the struct? That field is a pointer to the struct, right? But it looks recursive(?). I haven't seen such a style before, what does that mean? What is the purpose of such writing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can a field be of the same type as the struct?

It can't, this won't compile (note that the `node` data member is not a pointer in this example):

```
struct node {
    double value;
    node next;
};
```

But with `node *next` being a pointer it works, because the compiler knows that `node*` will be the size of a pointer on your machine.

> That field is a pointer to the struct, right?

Correct.

> But it looks recursive(?)

Correct. It reflects how linked lists work. Each item refers to the next, until the next is a sentinel (`nullptr`).

> I haven't seen such a style before, what does that mean?

Not sure what you mean by "such as style". The essence is that you can declare a type, say `struct MyDataType;` and then have pointers or references to it, without having the complete type definition available. This is a common technique for multiple goals. The one you presented here, but also PIMPL idiom and much more.

> What is the purpose of such writing?

Hopefully, the answers to the questions above have answered this one, too :)

Answer (score 1):

A `node*` is not a `node`. If you want you can call it "recursion" because every `node` can have a member that points to another `node`. Though it is **not** an infinite recursion, because a `node*` **can** point to a `node` but it not necessarily does so. When I create a `node` like this:

```
 node n;
```

Then that `node` has an uninitialzed `next` member. Nothing recursive about that.

> What is the purpose of such writing?

In a linked list, typically each node has a link to the next node in the list. This can be implemented by `node` having a `node* next` member.